# Why my sales aren't showing in Magento 2 Admin Panel?

Tags: magento2, database, sales-order, admin-panel, order-grid

I can see my sales in **sales_order** table, though, I can't see in **sales_order_grid**.

I guess that it's some related to it, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it disabling the **asynchronous indexing**, so flush the cache and reindex again.

Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Grid Settings > Asynchronous indexing

[image: Magento 2 Asynchronous indexing]

Comment: hi @Rafael, I my case grid not showing if new admin user created, Role is Administrator, still its not showing

Comment: @jafarpinjar did you reindex?

Comment: yes, I posted in question also @Rafael